# Value of pointer variable changing when value stored in succeding locations is modified

Tags: c, pointers

This is the C code I executed.

```
    int *a, *b,*c,d;
    a=&d;
    printf("1 a=%p &d=%p\n", a,&d);
    b=a+1;
    printf("2 a=%p &d=%p b=%p\n", a,&d,b);
    c=a+2;
    printf("3 a=%p &d=%p b=%p c=%p\n", a, &d,b,c);
    *b=34;
    printf("4 a=%p &d=%p b=%p c=%p\n", a, &d,b,c);
    d=342;
    printf("5 a=%p &d=%p b=%p c=%p\n", a, &d,b,c);
    *c=21;
    printf("6 a=%p &d=%p b=%p c=%p\n", a, &d,b,c);
    *b=37;
    printf("7 a=%p &d=%p b=%p c=%p\n", a, &d,b,c);
    *c=29;
    printf("8 a=%p &d=%p b=%p c=%p\n", a, &d,b,c);
```

The output I got was unexpected as I expected the value of 'a' to remain the same as &d. But the actual output was:

> 1 a=0x7ffd0267145c &d=0x7ffd0267145c
> 2 a=0x7ffd0267145c &d=0x7ffd0267145c b=0x7ffd02671460
> 3 a=0x7ffd0267145c &d=0x7ffd0267145c b=0x7ffd02671460 c=0x7ffd02671464
> 4 a=0x7ffd00000022 &d=0x7ffd0267145c b=0x7ffd02671460 c=0x7ffd02671464
> 5 a=0x7ffd00000022 &d=0x7ffd0267145c b=0x7ffd02671460 c=0x7ffd02671464
> 6 a=0x1500000022 &d=0x7ffd0267145c b=0x7ffd02671460 c=0x7ffd02671464
> 7 a=0x1500000025 &d=0x7ffd0267145c b=0x7ffd02671460 c=0x7ffd02671464
> 8 a=0x1d00000025 &d=0x7ffd0267145c b=0x7ffd02671460 c=0x7ffd02671464

I tried experimenting by a different modification

```
int *a, *b,*c,d;
    a=&d;
    printf("1 a=%p &d=%p\n", a,&d);
    b=a+4;
    printf("2 a=%p &d=%p b=%p\n", a,&d,b);
    c=a+8;
    printf("3 a=%p &d=%p b=%p c=%p\n", a, &d,b,c);
    *b=34;
    printf("4 a=%p &d=%p b=%p c=%p\n", a, &d,b,c);
    d=342;
    printf("5 a=%p &d=%p b=%p c=%p\n", a, &d,b,c);
    *c=21;
    printf("6 a=%p &d=%p b=%p c=%p\n", a, &d,b,c);
    *b=37;
    printf("7 a=%p &d=%p b=%p c=%p\n", a, &d,b,c);
    *c=29;
    printf("8 a=%p &d=%p b=%p c=%p\n", a, &d,b,c);
    return 0;
```

This gave the output:

> 1 a=0x7ffc674b76dc &d=0x7ffc674b76dc
> 2 a=0x7ffc674b76dc &d=0x7ffc674b76dc b=0x7ffc674b76ec
> 3 a=0x7ffc674b76dc &d=0x7ffc674b76dc b=0x7ffc674b76ec c=0x7ffc674b76fc
> 4 a=0x7ffc674b76dc &d=0x7ffc674b76dc b=0x22674b76ec c=0x7ffc674b76fc
> 5 a=0x7ffc674b76dc &d=0x7ffc674b76dc b=0x22674b76ec c=0x7ffc674b76fc
> 6 a=0x7ffc674b76dc &d=0x7ffc674b76dc b=0x22674b76ec c=0x7ffc674b76fc
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

What is causing this unexpected behavior?

Comment: int is  most likely 4 bytes, pointer 8

Comment: But shouldn't b=a+1 automatically point to a location that is 'one int size' after &d? I added 4 just to be sure, but it is giving a different behavior so I posted that code as well, in case it gives a better insight.

Comment: Where do you think that a+1 points?  To what memory?

Comment: When your program evaluates `*b=34;`, and `b` is pointing to one `int` beyond `d`, what do you think is there? Why would you not expect the bytes that are there to be some of the bytes used for `a`? Or why would you expect them? The compiler is allowed to place `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` wherever it chooses, so it could place `a` after `d` or not.

Comment: Indeed @EricPostpischil. Thank you very much. I tried by doing b=a+9(9 bytes is large enough to 'jump' a), and the output was as expected.

Comment: You may set a pointer value to be one location after the object to which it referred, but dereferencing it is *undefined behaviour*. Also note that with pointer arithmetic `b=a+9` does not necessarily add 9 bytes: it adds `9 * sizeof *a` bytes. Pointer arithmetic works like array indexing. A distance of `1` is one *element*.

Answer (score 0):

If a pointer does not store the address of an object, then you cannot dereference that pointer, or it will cause undefined behavior.

(That is, you cannot dereference an address that is "empty".)

In your code, dereferencing `b` and `c` causes undefined behavior.

If you want your code works, you can declare an array:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int d[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    int *a = &d[0];
    int *b = a + 1;
    int *c = a + 2;
    *a = 4;
    *b = 5;
    *c = 6;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", d[0], d[1], d[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs `4 5 6`.